# Facebook /{object-id}/likes - Error#803 "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"

Tags: facebook, rest

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%7B751199848395776%7D%2Flikes&version=v2.9

```
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {751199848395776}",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 803,
        "fbtrace_id": "BvhO4SGizLJ"
      }
    }
```

**751199848395776/likes**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "BBG7Nujj+PC"
  }
}
```

Comment: `{object-id}` Is only a number. It does not include the brackets...

Comment: 751199848395776/likes

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "BBG7Nujj+PC"
  }
}

Comment: And what do you not understand about that error? Look up the word *deprecated*, and look at your API version

Comment: Please Help How to works in versions v2.4 and higher

Comment: Read the API documentation. I was only here for the Android tag, which your question isn't about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change Api Level 2.3**

```
{
  "id": "751199848395776",
  "from": {
    "name": "Keshav Gera",
    "id": "303261006522998"
  },
  "updated_time": "2017-06-09T05:59:33+0000",
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "124778301449917",
        "name": "Manisha Gera"
      },
      {
        "id": "1680577265523548",
        "name": "Rubi Sharma"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTI0Nzc4MzAxNDQ5OTE3",
        "after": "MTY4MDU3NzI2NTUyMzU0OAZDZD"
      }
    }
  },
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2017-06-26T04:54:27+0000",
        "from": {
          "name": "Manisha Gera",
          "id": "124778301449917"
        },
        "message": "Working",
        "can_remove": false,
        "like_count": 1,
        "user_likes": true,
        "id": "751199848395776_760186854163742"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2017-06-26T05:00:17+0000",
        "from": {
          "name": "Keshav Gera",
          "id": "303261006522998"
        },
        "message": "hi",
        "can_remove": false,
        "like_count": 0,
        "user_likes": false,
        "id": "751199848395776_760188187496942"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOell3TVRnMk9EVTBNVFl6TnpReU9qRTBPVGcwTlRJNE5qYz0ZD",
        "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOell3TVRnNE1UZAzNORGsyT1RReU9qRTBPVGcwTlRNeU1UYz0ZD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: using through likes array size